# how to use org.bluez.AudioSource GetProperty

Tags: c, bluetooth, dbus, a2dp

how can i check weather the given device is connected. using org.bluez.AudioSource GetProperty
I am using c and DBus,can anybody help me to get out of this...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've been looking into the *`BlueZ D-BUS API`* which is a precious documentation for everything related to listening on BlueZ's signals and query information. You can find it in any BlueZ source in the `doc/` folder.

To check if a device is connected, you first need to get all the Bluetooth devices on your computer and their *paths* using D-BUS, I will not provide any C documentation as you can easily find plenty of examples about this using Google. I will instead show you what D-BUS calls you can make via `dbus-send` to get such an information.

**Get Devices list:**

```
dbus-send --system \  
  --dest=org.bluez \  
  --print-reply /  \  
  org.bluez.Manager.GetProperties
```

This returns an array of adapters with their paths.
Once you have these path(s) you can retrieve the list of all the Bluetooth devices paired with your adapter(s).

**Get paired devices:**

```
dbus-send --system \  
  --print-reply \  
  --dest=org.bluez \  
  /org/bluez/{pid}/hci0 \  
  org.bluez.Adapter.GetProperties
```

This gives you the list of paired devices within the `Devices` array field.

Once you have the list of devices paired to your Bluetooth Adapter, you can know if it is connected to the AudioSource interface.

**Get the devices connected to the AudioSource interface :**

```
dbus-send --system \  
  --print-reply \  
  --dest=org.bluez \  
  /org/bluez/{pid}/hci0/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX \  
  org.bluez.AudioSource.GetProperties
```

I find it more to convenient to first try d-bus calls using `dbus-send` because the D-BUS C API is a bit confusing and inconvenient to use.

Comment: this Observation might be useful.

On `BlueZ version 4.98`, org.bluez.AudioSource.GetProperties throws `error:`  

Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetProperties" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.AudioSource" doesn't exist


On `BlueZ version 4.101`, it `works:`

method return sender=:1.2 -> dest=:1.51 reply_serial=2
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "State"
         variant             string "disconnected"
      )
   ]

Comment: Thanks noticing it. Seems like a bug in BlueZ (https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/36080).